# Remove an index from a one-to-one relationship [TypeORM]

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, typescript, typeorm

I would like to know if it is possible to drop an index from a one-to-one relationship with TypeORM.

```
@OneToOne(() => Customer, {
    cascade: true
})
@JoinColumn({
    name: 'customer',
    referencedColumnName: 'uid'
})
customer: Customer
```

I looked on the doc and didn't find anything interesting, tried things that I found on google like used **@Index()** but nothing conclusive as well.
[image]

I cannot add another row because I have this error message showing

```
ER_DUP_ENTRY: Duplicate entry 'f57c' for key 'REL_e8ed1ed567c8f9315acc836631'
```

Thank you in advance for your help ❤️

Comment: I think you're just writing a model using TypeORM, You should use migration for any database-related operations that you can go back to easily in the future.. as of now I think you need to delete the index directly from the database only.

Comment: @Shubham I will try, but suddenly what is the **synchronize** parameter for if to use migrations, because I set it to true ? ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found ! It is possible to add create **createForeignKeyConstraints: false** to delete the index of a relation

```
@OneToOne(() => Table, {
    cascade: true,
    createForeignKeyConstraints: false
})
```